# Removing user points using rules module?

Tags: rules, userpoints

I've made a rule to add userpoints by

Add user points rule

**Events**
1.A node has been flagged, under "MyFlag"

**Actions**

1.flagged-node:author
 2.Value 1
 3.Point Category General

How do you remove user points using rules?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the value of the "Points" field a negative number.

Let's say you want to remove 100 points when the flag event occurs.

Make the value for Points equal to -100.

Hope that helps.